# In VB.net, using OLEDB, in one execution, how do I UPDATE a column value that is also referenced in 'GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(*) ...' query?

Tags: vb.net, group-by, count, oledb, having

I thought this would be simple task.
I was wrong!

The record with Name'A' and Number'2' needs to have it's Number changed to '0'.

Likewise with the records of Name'B', Number'1' and Name'B', Number'2'.

Why do I get "Syntax error in UPDATE statement."?

What am I missing?

Your generous help will be greatly appreciated!

My Code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Private sNameColumn As String = "Name"
    Private sNumberColumn As String = "Number"
    Private sFlagColumn As String = "Flag"
    Private sOutputFormat As String = "'{0,-20} {1,10} {2,10} {3,10}"

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown

        Dim oledbMyConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" &
                                                "Data Source = C:\0\NameAndNumber.mdb;" &
                                                "Persist Security Info=True;" &
                                                "Jet OLEDB:" &
                                                "Database Password=123"
                                                )

        oledbMyConn.Open()

        Dim sTableName As String = "NameAndNumber"
        Dim sGroupQuery As String = " GROUP BY " & sNameColumn & ", " & sNumberColumn & " HAVING COUNT(*) = 1"
        Dim sMyQuery As String = ""

        Dim ds As DataSet = Nothing
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = Nothing


        sMyQuery =
            "SELECT * FROM " & sTableName
        Debug.Print("'============================================ look at the table")
        Debug.Print("'Query: " & sMyQuery)
        ds = New DataSet(sTableName)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sMyQuery, oledbMyConn)
        Try
            da.Fill(ds, sTableName)
            ShowResults("Table contents", ds)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("'Exception message: " & ex.Message)
        End Try

        sMyQuery =
            "SELECT" &
            " " & sNameColumn & ", " & sNumberColumn &
            " FROM " & sTableName &
            sGroupQuery
        Debug.Print("'============================================ see if any records qualify")
        Debug.Print("'Query: " & sMyQuery)
        ds = New DataSet(sTableName)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sMyQuery, oledbMyConn)
        Try
            da.Fill(ds, sTableName)
            ShowResults("Qualifying records", ds)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("'" & ex.Message)
        End Try

        Dim sMyUpdate As String =
            "UPDATE " & sTableName &
            " SET" &
            " " & sNumberColumn & " = '0'," &
            " " & sFlagColumn & " = 'P'" &
            sGroupQuery
        Debug.Print("'============================================ try to update the qualifying records")
        Debug.Print("'Update command: " & sMyUpdate)
        Dim com As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
        With com
            .Connection = oledbMyConn
            .CommandText = sMyUpdate
            Try
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.Print("'Exception message: " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End With

        sMyQuery =
            "SELECT * FROM " & sTableName
        Debug.Print("'============================================ look at the table again")
        Debug.Print("'Query: " & sMyQuery)
        ds = New DataSet(sTableName)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sMyQuery, oledbMyConn)
        Try
            da.Fill(ds, sTableName)
            ShowResults("Table contents", ds)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("'Exception message: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub ShowResults(ByVal sTitle As String, ByRef ds As DataSet)
        Dim sCol0Val As String = ""
        Dim sCol1Val As String = ""
        Dim sCol2Val As String = ""
        With ds
            If .Tables IsNot Nothing AndAlso .Tables.Count > 0 Then
                Debug.Print(String.Format(sOutputFormat, sTitle, sNameColumn, sNumberColumn, sFlagColumn))
                With .Tables(0)
                    For r As Integer = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1
                        sCol0Val = ""
                        sCol1Val = ""
                        sCol2Val = ""
                        Try
                            sCol0Val = .Rows(r).Item(0)
                            sCol1Val = .Rows(r).Item(1)
                            sCol2Val = .Rows(r).Item(2)
                        Catch
                        End Try

                        Debug.Print(
                            String.Format(
                                sOutputFormat,
                                "Record # " & r.ToString,
                                sCol0Val,
                                sCol1Val,
                                sCol2Val
                                )
                            )
                    Next
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Debug.Prints:

```
'============================================ look at the table
'Query: SELECT * FROM NameAndNumber
'Table contents             Name     Number       Flag
'Record # 0                    A          1           
'Record # 1                    A          1           
'Record # 2                    A          2           
'Record # 3                    B          1           
'Record # 4                    B          2           
'Record # 5                    B          3           
'Record # 6                    B          3           
'============================================ see if any records qualify
'Query: SELECT Name, Number FROM NameAndNumber GROUP BY Name, Number HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
'Qualifying records         Name     Number       Flag
'Record # 0                    A          2           
'Record # 1                    B          1           
'Record # 2                    B          2           
'============================================ try to update the qualifying records
'Update command: UPDATE NameAndNumber SET Number = '0', Flag = 'P' GROUP BY Name, Number HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
'Exception message: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.
'============================================ look at the table again
'Query: SELECT * FROM NameAndNumber
'Table contents             Name     Number       Flag
'Record # 0                    A          1           
'Record # 1                    A          1           
'Record # 2                    A          2           
'Record # 3                    B          1           
'Record # 4                    B          2           
'Record # 5                    B          3           
'Record # 6                    B          3
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a `GROUP BY` in an `UPDATE` statement. The point of a `GROUP BY` is to create a single record in the result set from multiple records in the data source. That means that the records in the result set don't actually exist in the data source, so how could you possibly update them? You need to rethink your logic and you also need to read some SQL documentation and don't just make up syntax because you think it should work.

Comment: So what is the actual aim here? Is it to find records with unique combinations of `Name` and `Number` and set their `Number` to zero? If so then, off the top of my head, I think you might have to do one query to get the unique combinations, another query to get the IDs with those combinations and then an update where the ID is in that list. There may be a more efficient way but I can't think of one now.

Comment: I guess another option would be to use a cursor, although I'm not even sure that that is supported in Access and you might not be able to do it using ADO.NET even if it is.

Comment: Why not just use a WHERE clause `WHERE ( ([Name] = 'A' AND [Number] = 0) OR ([Name] = 'B' AND ([Number] = 1 OR [Number] = 2)))`

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b, if I'm reading the question correctly, the OP cannot hard-code those combinations because they don't know what they are. The whole point of the `GROUP BY` is to find those combinations for which there is only one record so that those records can then be updated. You could certainly query the database and then dynamically generate a `WHERE` clause like the one you suggest but it can't be hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you jmcilhinney for your response.
It became obvious that iteration based on the 'GROUP BY' results was the only way to achieve what I want.

Also, the SET command needed to have the Number column bracketed. Found that through trial and error testing.

The 'GROUP BY' code, then the iteration based on that result, then the updated table:

```
sMyQuery =
            "SELECT" &
            " " & sNameColumn & ", " & sNumberColumn &
            " FROM " & sTableName &
            sGroupQuery
        Debug.Print("'============================================ see if any records qualify")
        Debug.Print("'Query: " & sMyQuery)
        ds = New DataSet(sTableName)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sMyQuery, oledbMyConn)
        Try
            da.Fill(ds, sTableName)
            ShowResults("Qualifying records", ds)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("'" & ex.Message)
        End Try

        Dim sMyUpdate As String = ""
        Dim com As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
        With com
            .Connection = oledbMyConn
            With ds.Tables(0)
                For Each r As DataRow In .Rows
                    sMyUpdate =
                        "UPDATE " & sTableName &
                        " SET" &
                        " [" & sNumberColumn & "] = '0', " & sFlagColumn & " = 'P'" &
                        " WHERE " &
                        sNameColumn & " = '" & r.Item(sNameColumn).ToString & "'" &
                        " AND " &
                        sNumberColumn & " = '" & r.Item(sNumberColumn).ToString & "'"
                    com.CommandText = sMyUpdate
                    Try
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Debug.Print("'Exception message: " & ex.Message)
                    End Try
                Next
            End With
        End With
'============================================ look at the table again
'Query: SELECT * FROM NameAndNumber
'Table contents             Name     Number       Flag
'Record # 0                    A          1           
'Record # 1                    A          1           
'Record # 2                    A          0          P
'Record # 3                    B          0          P
'Record # 4                    B          0          P
'Record # 5                    B          3           
'Record # 6                    B          3
```